# Take data from UITabeVieCell to populate to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, settings

i have added my app to Chameleon Framework to generate random colors, i want to add internal setting to my app. for example  i created a tabelViewController VC and then i added a switch what i want is when mySwitch isOn i want chameleon colors to populate the tableViewCells and when its OFF i want the tableViewCells to be .systemBackgoundColor.

***My SettingsVC***

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Chameleon Color"
    let mySwitch = UISwitch()
    mySwitch.onTintColor = .blue
    mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTabSwitch(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    cell.accessoryView = mySwitch
    return cell
}

@objc func didTabSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch){
    if sender.isOn {
       // populate the chameleon framework color
    }
    else {
     // change to the default background color
    }
}
```

***ViewController***

```
/// Provides a cell object for each row.
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   // Fetch a cell of the appropriate type.
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row].name
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: list[indexPath.row].color)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(contrastingBlackOrWhiteColorOn: cell.backgroundColor, isFlat: true)
    
    if let date  = list[indexPath.row].date {
        let formater = DateFormatter()
        formater.timeZone = .current
        formater.locale = .current
        formater.timeStyle = .short
        formater.dateStyle = .none
        
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = formater.string(from: date)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor(contrastingBlackOrWhiteColorOn: cell.backgroundColor, isFlat: true)
    }
   return cell
}
```

any help or hint would appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes down to "how do I communicate between different components of my app". Since I assume you don't only want to inform your `ViewController` of the color change but rather update the entire UI  (like applying a theme) the easiest way would be to use the `NotificationCenter` and provide it the color so all components interested in the change can observe it.

```
public extension NSNotification.Name {
  static let ColorChanged = Self(rawValue: "color_changed")
}

@objc func didTabSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch){
  if sender.isOn {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .ColorChanged, object: UIColor.randomFlat)
  }
  else {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .ColorChanged, object: nil)
  }
}
```

In **ViewController** (or other interested components)

```
private var chameleonColor: UIColor? {
  didSet {
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
 
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(updateColor),
    name: .ColorChanged,
    object: nil
  )
}

@objc private func updateColor(_ notification: Notification) {
  chameleonColor = notification.object as? UIColor
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  // ...
  cell.backgroundColor = chameleonColor ?? .systemBackgroundColor
}
```